# Figure out next page in pagebeforehide event - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an app that lists a number of objects and, having selected one allows its various  facets to be edited by drilling down into detail  pages. It is implemented as multiple pages in a single HTML file.
If the model objects were cars the page hierarchy might look like this:

- CarListPage

  - SingleCarOverviewPage

    - CarEngineDetailsPage
    - CarColourDetailsPage

I'd like to prompt the user to save any changes to a car as they exit the SingleCarOverviewPage heading *back* to the main CarListPage. I've looked at handling the "pageBeforeHide" event on SingleCarOverviewPage but that also triggers as I transition forward into the detail pages. Where is the best point to hook this handler in?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do -

```
$('#SingleCarOverviewPage').on('pagebeforehide', function(event, data){
    if (data.nextPage.attr('id') == 'CarListPage'){
        // handle your stuffs here
    }
});
```

You could also do -

```
$('#SingleCarOverviewPage').on('pagebeforechange', function(event, data){
    if (data.nextPage.attr('id') == 'CarListPage'){
        // handle your stuffs here
    }
});
```

I'd use the `pagebeforehide` instead of `pagebeforechange` in this scenario - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Great stuff. One small modification - I had to check data.nextPage.attr('id') not "toPage" - if you can modify the above I'll accept this as the answer. Many thanks!

Comment: @MarkH Hey you're welcome, glad I could help.  Out of curiosity, what version of jQM are you using?

Comment: @MarkH I updated the answer to check `data.NextPage.attr('id')` instead of `data.toPage.attr('id')`.  I think the latter is for older versions of jQM.

Comment: I'm using JQM 1.3.1. Thanks again.